# unable to login to IBM Cloud private 2.1.0.3 docker registry

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud-private

I have a newly installed ICP 2.1.0.3

I have set up my etc/hosts so that mycluster.icp  points to the IP address.

I have configured docker so that docker info lists:

Insecure Registries:
 mycluster.icp:8500

Yet when I try to log into the docker registry using the user/password admin/admin I receive the following error:

{

```
   sudo docker login mycluster.icp:8500
    Username: admin
    Password: 
    Error response from daemon: Get https://mycluster.icp:8500/v2/: Get https://mycluster.icp:8600/image-manager/api/v1/auth/token?account=admin&client_id=docker&offline_token=true&service=token-service: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers) (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I have tried re-installing the cluster but I get the same issue on the newly installed cluster.

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents .. Did you copy ca.crt from ICP to host you try to push image to ICP docker registry?  So something like that.. /etc/docker/certs.d/mycluster.icp:8500 make sure copy mycluster.icp:8500 along with ca.crt to your image push docker server at /etc/docker/certs.d